# How do I call C functions from Flash?

Tags: c, actionscript-3, flash

Currently I have a command line OSX executable that I am compiling in xcode.   I'm wondering if there is a way to call functions / interact with a flash or flex project. I found some information about a flex c++ bridge, but apparently it is only for windows.

Can this be done with air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to call C functions directly, but [AIR has a "native process API"](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/features/) for "communicating with native processes using standard input and output", which can work with a command line executables.

Comment: Lars, it appears you are totally correct, however, I Found some really interesting info on Alchemy. Apparently alchemy allows you to compile C code in the flex IDE, allowing you to utilize different C classes in flash labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html)

Answer (score 0):

you  need to use adobe Air 
check this 
Lynda.com AIR 2 with Flash and Flex Essential Training
http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourseNoTabs.aspx?lpk2=68629